# shiny:change tab when click on image

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

I'm building a Shiny application and some of my users (not very familiar with this kind of layout) don't understand that the application works with tabs and they just don't see where to go from the Homepage.

That's why I want to display a big infography on the main page, and when they click on it, it automatically activates the second tab. I know how to add a link to an image:

```
tags(a(img(src="image.png"), href="link.com"))
```

And I know how to programmatically select a different tab:

```
updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId="navbar", selected="tab2")
```

But how to combine those 2 actions?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you thought of using a NavBar menu rather than tab panels?

Comment: well, i had to put a lot of info on the homepage of the app, so the tabs are not so obvious to spot on the top. I'm not sure that adding a menu would solve it, though i could have a menu *in addition* to the image-click..

Comment: Just a thought. The Navbar menu is noticeable with most themes, and you can easily customize it (Navbar colors, etc.) with just a bit of css code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the image an `id`, and use the [`onclick()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/0.1.0/topics/onclick) function from `shinyjs`. Working example:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  img(id="my_img",src="image.png",style="cursor:pointer;"),
  useShinyjs(),
  tabsetPanel(id="navbar",
              tabPanel("tab1", p("This is tab 1")),
              tabPanel("tab2", p("This is tab 2"))
  )
)



server <- function(input, output,session){

  shinyjs::onclick("my_img",  updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId="navbar", selected="tab2"))

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Florian, i think i should really dig into the shinyjs packagr it' full of good stuff. The solution works perfectly, except maybe for the fact that the mouse icon does not change on hover (indicating that it's a kind of clickable link

Comment: Hi agenis, shinyjs is an awesome package by Dean Attali, well worth looking into more of his stuff, I learned a lot from his blogs/website. Anyway, changing the cursor can be done with some custom CSS, see the updated example.